# Function to remove entry from linked list in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm struggling with exercise 4 in chapter 10 of the Programming in C book by Kochan.

The task is the following:

> Write a function called `removeEntry()` to remove an entry from a
>   linked list. The sole argument to the procedure should be a pointer to
>   the list. Have the function remove the entry after the one pointed to
>   by the argument.

For some reason the function doesn't work. If I do a `printf()` inside it, it seems to work, but it doesn't work in `main()`. I thought that given I am passing a pointer, it will change the original (as opposed to passing by value). But clearly I'm not doing it right. Could anyone please help me see where I'm going wrong?

```
// Function to remove an entry from a linked list

#include <stdio.h>

struct entry
{
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct entry n1, n2, n3; // Original list

    struct entry *listPointer = &n1; // List pointer set up for iterating list

    void removeEntry(struct entry *pList);

    //listHead.next = &n1;  set list head to point to original beginning of list

    n1.value = 100;
    n1.next = &n2;

    n2.value = 200;
    n2.next = &n3;

    n3.value = 300;
    n3.next = (struct entry *) 0; // marks end of list


    // Print out values before removing entry
    printf("Before removing entry:\n");

    while (listPointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", listPointer->value);
        listPointer = listPointer->next;
    }

    // reset listPointer to point to n1
    listPointer = &n1;

    // run function (DOES NOT WORK)
    removeEntry(listPointer);

    // print out values after (supposedly) removing entry
    printf("\n\nAfter removing entry:\n");

    while (listPointer != (struct entry *) 0)
    {
        printf("%i\n", listPointer->value);
        listPointer = listPointer->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

/********************* REMOVE ENTRY ********************************/

void removeEntry(struct entry *pList)
{
    //  <-------&n2
    pList = pList->next;

}
```

Comment: "I thought that given I am passing a pointer, it will change the original". C does not have pass by reference. It's all pass by value. In this case you are passing the pointer by value. Any changes to the pointer value itself have no effect on the caller. Only changes to what the pointer points to will be seen by the caller. A simplified rule of thumb: Assignments that have an address/pointer deref on the LHS will be seen by the caller. Other assignments will not.

Comment: You need this: `void removeEntry(struct entry **pList) { *pList = (*pList)->next; }` and call it with `removeEntry(&listPointer);`

Comment: If you want to remove the *following* item first check there *is* a following item. Remember its pointer. Copy *that* node's `next` pointer to the current node's `next` pointer. Then `free` the pointer that you remembered (the next node).

Comment: Thank you kaylum, that's amazing! But why did I need a double pointer? Sorry, I clearly need to learn more about pointers (hopefully I will after this chapter!)

Comment: If you want to change an int you need a pointer to an int. If you want to change a char you need a pointer to a char. If you want to change a pointer you need a pointer to a pointer. I hope that pattern is obvious :-)  ANd yes, please do review the text book.

Comment: Thank you, you've been really helpful (and yes, now that you say it it seems obvious....) :-)

Comment: There is no need for a double pointer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are three misunderstanding in your code:

First as mentioned by kaylum in his comment, function arguments are passed by value in C. It means that whenever you pass an argument to a function, a copy of the argument is used within the function. And when the function returns, this copy is lost. So you won't be able to change `pList`'s value within `removeEntry()` as you inteded.

The second issue (which is somehow linked) is that your function `removeEntry()` is supposed to remove the entry just after the one pointed to by the function argument. So if `pList` points to an entry, you should remove the entry pointed by pList->next. If you do so, you will solve your first issue at the same time...

The third issue, is that you should check whether the element you want to remove does exists before removing it. Eventually, free the memory corresponding to the element you remove, but in your case this does not apply as you do not allocate entries dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, I realised that it wasn't quite right after re-reading the question (it does after all ask for a pointer to the list as an argument, and not a pointer to a pointer). I was so exited to have something that worked, that I missed the fact that I was removing the wrong item! (On the upside, I now know that you can have pointers to pointers...:-) I am now back to struggling to figure out how to access the entry I want to remove (as I only have one argument, I don't know how to get n2.next into pList->next). Hrmpf....

Comment: If you have a pointer to an entry, then you can access its members. As one of the member points to its next element, you can access to the next element too...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yay! Thanks to kaylum and Heyji I finally managed this! Thank you both!

Always funny with C how a problem seems so difficult, and when you figure it out you wonder how you could ever have struggled with something so simple....

```
void removeEntry(struct entry *pList)
{
    struct entry *pTemp = pList->next;
    //  <-------&n3
    pList->next = pTemp->next;

}
```